# EF Core get a exception: "The of entity type 'xxx' cannot be tracked"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a block of code like the following:

```
var updatingEntity = new List<UpdateEntity>();

foreach (var item in List)
{
    ....
    // Logic here
    updatingEntity.Add(item);
}

if (updatingEntity.Count > 0)
{
    DbContext.Repository<UpdateEntity>().UpdateRange(UpdateEntity);
}

// Inserts some entity
// Exception happens here
var addingSomeEntity = new List<updatingEntity>();

foreach (var newItem in newList)
{
    ....
    // Logic here
    updatingEntity.Add(newItem);
 }

 if (updatingEntity.Count > 0)
 {
     await DbContext.Repository<UpdateEntity>().AddRangeAsync(addingSomeEntity);
 }
```

When I check my application insight. I get an exception at line

```
var addingSomeEntity = new List<updatingEntity>();
```

> The instance of entity type 'xxxx' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'log' to see the conflicting key values.

Can you explain to me why that line of code throws an exception? And is there any case where it still runs without throwing an exception?
It's great if you have a solution to improve!

Comment: The exception doesn't happen there. You are running a release build, there is not a 1-1 mapping between instructions and lines of code. When `.UpdateRange` returns, that line is the next instruction, where your code will resume.

Comment: It cannot be from that line. And that line is invalid anyway (the code won't even compile). It's probably one of the `UpdateRange` or `AddRange` calls which is throwing exception, and the 'xxx' inside the message is telling you which object type is already tracked. It's could be either your object or some object coming from navigation properties.

Comment: Thanks! I got it. Assuming that the function name is abcAsync(). I call it 3 times await abcAsync(); await abcAsync();await abcAsync(); Can that exception occur?

Comment: Can't answer this if we don't see the classes and the content of things like `List`.

Answer (score -1):

Lets simplify your example a little;

```cs
if (argumentBool)
{
    method();
}
method();
```

Then [decompile](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxFANgHwAICYCMBYAKAwGYACbUgYVIG9DSHSAHAJygDcIEBTcgFlJhuCABYB7ACYAKAJQ0AvvUYl+pALJTgYsSlIQWAcwCuQmAgBC2lDNpLGjKADNSU/cdMWrMu/dsFfAYLC4tIyANw+9or+gUKikrIRMQzR8kA===) it;

```
IL_0000: ldarg.1
IL_0001: brfalse.s IL_0009

IL_0003: ldarg.0
IL_0004: call instance void C::'method'()

IL_0009: ldarg.0
IL_000a: call instance void C::'method'()
```

When you call a method, the runtime first increments the program counter, then pushes that location onto a call stack. That's a basic feature of how all CPU's execute method calls.

When an exception is thrown, the runtime examines this call stack to reconstruct the  source locations in the stack trace.

In a debug build, the compiler will insert `nop` instructions to make sure that all source locations with breakpoints, or any location that you might want in a stack trace have a 1-1 mapping back to your source code.

But in a release build there is no IL instruction representing the '}' of the above if test. So if the first call to `method()` threw an exception, the source location in the stack trace would point to the second `method()` call.

Not because that is where the relevant call instruction was, but because that is the location of the next instruction that will execute.

Back to your example. It's not the `new List<updatingEntity>()` that's throwing an exception. It's the previous instruction calling `.UpdateRange(UpdateEntity);`

Comment: Yeah, but still doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Obviously that doesn't explain why the exception was thrown. But I'm sure there's a dupe for that question already.